# How to map Vim command and CTRL-W R together?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

### Problem

I am trying to map the `F10` key with the`terminal bash %` command so I can execute the current open file with bash in a split pane setup (this functions works). The problem is when I try to add the key combo `CTRL-W R` to swap the vim pane positions in the mapping, the positions do not swap. When I type `CTRL-W R` manually, it works.

This is the line that I have in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <F10> :terminal bash % <cr> <C-w> <C-r>
```

I have also tried adding a pipe and changing `noremap` to `map` but that did not solve anything.

```
map <F10> :terminal bash % <cr> | <C-w> r
```

### Question

Is is there a way to combine Vim commands (eg `:terminal bash %`) with `CTRL-W R` in a single `nnoremap` line?

Comment: You should keep the `<C-w>...` commands for normal mode operations since it's a normal mode command. In the command like you should try to use [`:h :wincmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd) instead (this is why this command exists). Otherwise the right approach to execute normal mode commands in the command line is to use [`:h :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal)

Comment: If you don't include the spaces (`:nnoremap <f10> :terminal bash %<enter><C-w>r`) does it work?

Comment: Hi @Luna we are trying to answer your question fully :-) Are you still searching a solution at your problem? Could precise what is not already answered?

Comment: @statox - I just discovered :wincmd thanks!

Comment: I have discovered the problem.  My script took about 5 seconds to fully execute with `:terminal bash %`. tThat paned seemed to have been locked which prevented  `<C-w>r`. It also prevented me from typing any command with `:` .  I would have to CTRL-WW to go back to the original pane to swap positions.

Comment: My objective was accomplished with `nnoremap  <F9> :w!; bel terminal bash % <cr>`

Answer (score 1):

I would propose:

```
nnoremap <F10> :terminal bash % <cr>:wincmd r<cr>
```

As @Matt mention in his comment `:wincmd r` is the command that is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`r`.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation could accompany the proposal?